# How to call through real class on non contempled scenarios on Mockery

Tags: php, unit-testing, mockery

Given this class:

```
MyClass
{   
    public function getValueFrom($foo)
    {
        return 'data';
    }
}
```

I want to test a certain calls to function `getValueFrom` with specific arguments:

```
$mock = Mockery::mock(MyClass);
$mock->shouldReceive('getValueFrom')
    ->with('foo')
    ->once()
    ->andReturn('bar');

(new MyClass)->foo('foo'); // returns bar
(new MyClass)->foo('someting-else'); // throws Mockery\Exception\NoMatchingExpectationException
```

If I make call to the same method with arguments distinct from 'foo' it throws NoMatchingExpectationException. How to delegate to the real class the non contempled scenarios? The spected behaviour is:

```
$mock = Mockery::mock(MyClass);
$mock->shouldReceive('getValueFrom')
    ->with('foo')
    ->once()
    ->andReturn('bar');

(new MyClass)->foo('foo'); // returns bar
(new MyClass)->foo('someting-else'); // return data
(new MyClass)->foo('anything-else'); // return data
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent errors commented, this would work:

```
$mock = Mockery::mock(MyClass);
$mock->shouldReceive('getValueFrom')
    ->with('foo')
    ->once()
    ->andReturn('bar');

// here!!
$mock->shouldDeferMissing();

(new MyClass)->foo('foo'); // returns bar
(new MyClass)->foo('someting-else'); // return data
(new MyClass)->foo('anything-else'); // return data
```